# Orthogonal transformation between vectors of the same norm

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a vector space over a field not of characteristic $2$, and is equipped with an inner product. I want to show that, given vectors $v$ and $w$ of the same norm, there is some orthogonal (inner-product-preserving) transformation taking $v$ to $w$.

Any help would be appreciated. I was toying with the reflection $$R_z(x) := x - 2\frac{x \cdot z}{\left|\left|z\right|\right|^2}z,$$ which negates $z$ and fixes its orthogonal complement pointwise. I am not sure if that is helpful.

(Note: The set of notes I've been given lists this as Witt's Lemma, but upon researching that, it seems to be quite complicated and involve machinery out of my reach.)

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to know here that a transformation $T: V \to V$ is orthogonal iff it maps orthonormal bases to orthonormal bases. (If this isn't familiar to you, you might like to prove it as an exercise.)

By construction $$v_1 := \frac{v}{||v||}$$ has unit length (here $||v|| := \sqrt{\langle v, v\rangle}$), so we can extend it to an orthonormal basis $(v_a)$ of $V$, and similarly we can extend $$w_1 := \frac{w}{||w||}$$ to an orthogonal basis $(w_a)$ of $V$. Then, by the above fact, the transformation $T: V \to V$ characterized by $$T: v_a \mapsto w_a, \qquad a = 1, \ldots, n,$$ is orthogonal, and in particular, it maps $v$ to $w$ as desired:
$$T(v) = T(||v|| v_1) = ||v|| T(v_1) = ||w|| w_1 = w.$$

Comment: What if the norm is $v \cdot v$? Does that change things?

Comment: Instead of the square root, that is.

Comment: I ask as the problem is for a generic inner product.

Comment: There's no choice in the norm here, it's simply the one the inner product defines. (Anyway, $v \mapsto v \cdot v$ does not satisfy the Triangle Inequality, so it is not a norm in the first place.)

Comment: I believe your response is valid only if $|v|=|w|$. Did I miss something ?

Comment: @Souza It's a prerequisite for the original statement to be true, and the title of the post asserts that it holds. I've edited the body of the question to include that hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

To reflect $v$ across a plane through the origin to $w$, we must reflect through the plane orthogonal to $w - v$. That reflection is
$$R_{v - w}(x) = x - 2 \frac{x \cdot (v - w)}{(v - w) \cdot (v - w)} (v - w) .$$
(If $w = v$ this reflection is undefined, but in that case the identity transformation satisfies our original condition; we thus henceforth assume $w \neq v$.)

> To verify that his transformation works, we must check that $R_{v - w}(v) = w$. Computing gives $$R_{v - w}(v) = v - 2 \frac{v \cdot (v - w)}{(v - w) \cdot (v - w)} (v - w) .$$ Writing both terms of the right-hand side with a common denominator and writing the resulting numerator as a linear combination of $v, w$ gives $$\frac{[(v - w) \cdot (v - w) - 2 v \cdot (v - w)] v + 2 v \cdot (v - w) w}{(v - w) \cdot (v - w)} .$$ Now, $$2 v \cdot (v - w) = 2 v \cdot v - 2 v \cdot w = v \cdot v - 2 v \cdot w + w \cdot w = (v - w) \cdot (v - w),$$ so substituting leaves $R_{v - w}(v) = w$ as desired. (Since $R_{v - w}^2 = {\bf 1}$, we have $R_{v - w}(w) = v$, too.)